# Cannot resolve symbol 'BASE64Encoder'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, encryption

I am trying to make an encryption/decryption java class and I have found this one on the internet , but looks like that it gives me an error "Cannot resolve symbol 'BASE64Encoder'"

```
import java.security.*;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import sun.misc.*;


public class AES  {

        private static final String ALGO = "AES";
        private static final byte[] keyValue =
                new byte[] { 'T', 'h', 'e', 'B', 'e', 's', 't',
                        'S', 'e', 'c', 'r','e', 't', 'K', 'e', 'y' };

        public static String encrypt(String Data) throws Exception {
            Key key = generateKey();
            Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
            c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(Data.getBytes());
            String encryptedValue = new BASE64Encoder().encode(encVal);
            return encryptedValue;
        }

        public static String decrypt(String encryptedData) throws Exception 
{
            Key key = generateKey();
            Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
            c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
            byte[] decordedValue = new 
BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encryptedData);
            byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decordedValue);
            String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
            return decryptedValue;
        }
        private static Key generateKey() throws Exception {
            Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, ALGO);
            return key;
        }

    }
```

Comment: @shmosel: This is not a dupe of that question, this has nothing to do with Eclipse. This is simply caused by the fact that Android has none of the sun.* classes.

Comment: @JamesKPolk The answer is the same: don't use `sun.*`. I've added a more specific link.